# PF Keys for Host On-Demand on OS X

Tags: mainframe, zos, 3270, ibm-pcomm

I'm running IBM Host On-Demand on my Mac. I haven't found a way to enter PF Keys other than through clicking on the virtual keyboard in the application. Other 3270 emulators such as Brown University tn3270 allow for command+number key for PF key function. Is there a way to something similar on Host On-Demand? It is really slow to have to to use a mouse for function keys.

Comment: I use one of the other emulators on my Mac that has the same issue...something that's really helped me was to spring for the "extended" Apple wireless keyboard - it has all the keys you normally expect on a 3270 device, and they're even in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to ask a stupid question, but --- have you tried hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Fnn</kbd> (use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in the lower left)?  That's what I've had to do to use PF keys on HOD on my Macbook.

You can also set that behavior as default in the MacOS settings: under Keyboard, there's a checkbox that says "Press Fn key to..."

Comment: Yes, this does work, thanks. I was hoping to find a physical key combination. I can't touch type with the touchbar. :(  It is much nicer in the Brown tn3720 to press command+number.

Comment: Yeah, I have a Touch Bar too, and can relate. But as Milos mentions in his other response, you can lock in the PF keys with that Settings setting.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBookPro I checked the box in the keyboard System Preferences panel that says: "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" and I can use function keys in HOD.